# How to get the real time values of cryptocurrencies with given amount from a textfield

Tags: php, cryptocurrency

I would like to know how to get the real-time value of any cryptocurrency with the amount gotten from an input field

I've been able to get the value of bitcoin but will like to have access to not just bitcoin i.e. ETH, BCH, XRP ...

```
$url='https://bitpay.com/api/rates';
$json=json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ) );
$dollar=$btc=0;

foreach( $json as $obj ){
    if( $obj->code=='USD' )$btc=$obj->rate;
}

echo "1 bitcoin=\$" . $btc . "USD<br />";
$dollar=1 / $btc;
echo "10 dollars = " . round( $dollar * 10,8 )."BTC";
```

Input field value ($): `5000`
Cryptocurrency Selected: `ETH` (P.S: This value can change which results in a different output below)
Output: `0.45564`

Answer (score 1):

### You need to analyze better the bitpay return

BitPay API return something like this :

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'code' => 'BTC',
    'name' => 'Bitcoin',
    'rate' => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'code' => 'BCH',
    'name' => 'Bitcoin Cash',
    'rate' => 32.73192300000000187765181181021034717559814453125,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'code' => 'USD',
    'name' => 'US Dollar',
    'rate' => 9995.0199900000006891787052154541015625,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'code' => 'EUR',
    'name' => 'Eurozone Euro',
    'rate' => 8948.573474999999234569258987903594970703125,
  ),
[...]
  13 => 
  array (
    'code' => 'ETH',
    'name' => 'Ether',
    'rate' => 44.98208799999999740748535259626805782318115234375,
  ),
  14 => 
  array (
    'code' => 'AED',
    'name' => 'UAE Dirham',
    'rate' => 36714.5170240000006742775440216064453125,
  ),
```

You can therefore easily notice that it will not return the value of each crypto in USD but the value of each crypto and each currency in BTC.

You have managed to recover the value in USD so you can easily recover the value in ETH for example

```
$usd = 1;
$btc = 0;
$eth = 0;
foreach( $json as $obj ){
    if( $obj->code=='USD' )$btc=$obj->rate;
    if( $obj->code=='ETH' )$eth=$obj->rate;
}
```

All you have to do is find the mathematical formula that allows you to solve the equation.

```
($usd/$eth)*$btc
```

With current rate we find 227USD for 1ETH

All you have to do now is do the same for the other money